# Spacemacs visual line navigation not working

Tags: spacemacs, motion, visual-line-mode

Running spacemacs 0.200.13 on emacs 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 18.04.

In `~/.spacemacs`, there is:

```
(global-visual-line-mode t)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'visual-line-mode)
```

So, when I open a text file, I see long lines as multiple screen lines.

But when I press j or k, it moves according to actual line, not screen line. That is, j or k moves multiple screen lines.

`SPC h d k j` shows j bound to `evil-next-line`

What is happening here? How do I get j and k to move as per screen line even in normal mode?

Comment: This seems like expected behaviour... Movement does indeed occur according to actual lines, not screen lines, when in the `normal state`. When entering `insert state` and using the arrow keys up and down, you should move according to the screen line.

Comment: @EFLS Yes. I agree. Any idea how can one get the screen-line wise movement even in normal mode?

Comment: I think this is part of the `vim` emulation of `evil`. Since `vim` works with movements (characters, words, sentences, lines, etc.) rather than visual lines, I'd guess it is an indispensable part of the `vim` experience. I have to admit it was difficult to adopt this mindset at first, but once you get used to it, it becomes second nature. Make sure to learn the `vim` keys to move between sentences (`(` `)`), paragraphs (`[` `]`), words, etc. And also learn to use `avy` for easier movement.

Answer (score 2):

You want `spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation`. In addition to turning on `visual-line-mode`, it [rebinds](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/c7a103a772d808101d7635ec10f292ab9202d9ee/layers/%2Bdistributions/spacemacs-base/keybindings.el#L256) `j/k` to `evil-next/previous-visual-line`.

Comment: Yes. That is what I do. But I thought, once done, it applies to all subsequent buffers/ sessions.

Comment: I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/11417) to add a global toggle. Assuming it makes it into the 0.300 release, you'll be able to do `spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation-globally`. Until then, you should be able to survive by adding `spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation` to your `find-file-hook`.